# Is there a way to set Fixed Position for a Tablix in an Report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a static Tablix that is of a fixed size and doesn't grow.It needs to be placed exactly 3.5 inches from the bottom of the page.Above this static tablix is a Dynamic Tablix that can grow.Irrespective of the Number of records in the Dynamic Tablix I need the Static Tablix to be displayed at the exact position Always.

For Example: The Dynamic Tablix when having (`number of rows>n`) or (`number of rows<n`),The Static Tablix moves out of the required spot...Even when the Dynamic table grows and spills over to the next page,the Static Table moves out of spot. What can be done to keep the Dynamic table in the required Location always

Comment: Don't add further detail in the comments, simply edit your post to include the extra info.

Comment: So set the report margin on the bottom to 3.5inches and align the static Tablix at the bottom.  Without more detail on the report, you may also want to simply cut the data out of the Tablix and put it in the Footer so it repeats on each page.

Answer (score 0):

Put both tablixes into rectangles and assuming that your dynamic one doesn't grow larger than the page, your static one should stay where it is.

Comment: The dynamic one grows larger than the page!

Comment: And you want to static tablix to be the same on each page?  If so, put it in the report footer

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by adding an Empty Tablix and calculating the Number of rows it should need to have such that the Static Tablix comes to the required spot.Kept the Calculate Number of Rows in a ReportVariable and added that many blank rows to the new Empty Tablix